# Efficiently read and validate csv file in python

Tags: python, validation, csv, pandas

I've multiple csv files (<10 G) and I need to validate files one by one in an memory efficient way. my validations include

1-> file in properly delimited

2-> validate certain columns, as integers/decimals

3-> validate date format (eg. yyyy/MM/dd) for certain columns.

currently I'm using

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as myCSV:
        CSVreader = csv.reader(myCSV)
        for row in CSVreader:
                my_logic
```

and looping each row and validating conditions per row. is there any better libraries/methods available? I've heard about pandas don't know if it is memory efficient.

Comment: Define "better"? From about 26 viewers, am I the only one to think that an iterator over the rows of a CSV file is already highly efficient? If the number of columns would be large, then and only then would I consider looking for alternative implementations. As it stands, I find this question to be broad: you're asking for "better libraries/methods" without trying a few things and comparing memory usage or asking why implementation a is better than b.

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar loop that took forever using pandas and was able to speed it up quite a bit by using this trick:

```
for row in dataframe:
    some logic over row.col1, row.col2, etc...
```

becomes:

```
for (col1, col2, ...) in zip(dataframe.col1.values, dataframe.col2.values, ...):
    some logic over col1, col2, etc...
```

not sure how it goes with memory, but was able to handle pretty big files using a 64bit version of python.

Comment: for me memory is also a big constraint! I think zip (required columns) will take everything into memory, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TurboSullivan if you are using python3 then you are wrong.  In python 2 use `itertools.izip` to use `zip` functionality without loading everything into memory at once.